# How to convert any character encoding to UTF8 on PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on a web crawler that grabs data from sites all over the world, and is dealing with distinct languages and encodings.

Currently I'm using the following function, and it works in 99% of the cases. But there is this 1% that is giving me headaches.

```
function convertEncoding($str) {
    return iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), "UTF-8", $str);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using both iconv and mbstring? Use mb_convert_encoding if you want to use multibyte string extension.

Comment: i tried it... same return... any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than blindly trying to detect the encoding, you should first check if the page that you downloaded has a listed character set. The character set may be set in the HTTP response header, for example:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Or in the HTML as a meta tag, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Only if neither are available then try to guess the encoding with mb_detect_encoding() or other methods.

Comment: right... i mannually inputed a "from" enconding based on the header of the of this souce [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cp_ajN7Kqvc) . But still getting a malformed string :(

Comment: The source encoding from that YouTube page is UTF-8, so there's really nothing to convert here..

Comment: Done some others tests... getting positive results setting a from encoding :) ... tks for the tip

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to detect character set of a string in 100% rate since some character sets are subset of some others. Try setting character set explicitly if possible without mixing [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) and [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions. I recommend using a function like this and supplying **from charset** whenever possible:

```
function convertEncoding($str, $from = 'auto', $to = "UTF-8") {
    if($from == 'auto') $from = mb_detect_encoding($str);
    return mb_convert_encoding ($str , $to, $from); 
}
```

Comment: i'd tested it with your function setting the $from with the same encoding of the header of the source... same return :(

Comment: im testing with the following source [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cp_ajN7Kqvc)

Comment: Dear afaschutz, please read my answer carefully. I did not claim it will work for your situation. I explained why your way is not right and offered a better way.

Comment: ive understood that... tks for the tip

Comment: Also, most character sets/encodings use the same bytes as other ones, but with other meanings (like most of the ISO-8859-x ones). Sometimes one can reliably guess depending on the distribution of characters (which depends on the language), but often you will need bigger amounts of text for that to work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

You can try utf_encode($str).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#89789

Or you can replace the content type meta tag with

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

from header of crawled content